# drupal form submit not doing as expected

Tags: forms, drupal, submit

I am trying to submit a form using the submit button created like this:

```
$form['actions'] = array('#type' => 'actions');
$form['actions']['submit'] = array(

'#type' => 'submit',
'#value' => t('Submit'),
'#weight' => 5,
'#submit' => array('edit_form_submit'),
);
```

However when the form is submit the

```
function edit_form_submit($form, &$form_state){
      dsm('IM HERE!!!');
}
```

does not get run.

I have checked the usual things line:

the $form['#form_id'] is 'edit_form' and $form['#type'] is set to 'form'.

I'm not quite stuck on this. I do think it must be a simple overlooked problem but I dont see it.

Any Ideas??

If you require more information please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do it in this way , 
you have to do something like this

```
function mymodule_myfrom($form, &$form_state){

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#weight' => 5,
    );

    return $form;
}

function mymodule_myfrom_submit($form, &$form_values){

    dsm('IM HERE!!!');

}
```

To call your form do this

```
$myfrom=drupal_get_form('mymodule_myfrom');
print drupal_render($myfrom);
```

to see complete example check out this example module, you can find from example 
https://drupal.org/project/examples

Also you can check tutorials like this one
http://mrphp.com.au/blog/how-make-simple-form-module-drupal